# HTTP POST through proxy on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, post, proxy

I can not make any HTTP POST requests through a proxy in Google App Engine, with httplib (set_tunnel, it seems that is not supported: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/dist27/httplib.py?r=281&spec=svn281) nor urllib2.

The fact is that in the local test whether the requests seem to work, at least returns something, I do'n know if through proxy, or directly (both with httplib (set_tunnel) as with urllib2), but when I upload the changes to Google's servers nothing works.

The functions I use to make the requests are:

```
def __urllib2Post(self, post_args, tokenizer):
    Post = urllib.urlencode(post_args, doseq=True)
    headers = {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)", 
                #"Host": "servicios.mitele.es", 
                #"Accept-Encoding": "gzip", 
                "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", 
                "Referer": "http://static1.tele-cinco.net/comun/swf/playerMitele.swf",
                "Connection": "close", 
                "Accept-Language": "de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3", 
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                }
    url = "http://servicios.mitele.es" + tokenizer
    proxy_h = urllib2Local.ProxyHandler({"http" : "80.58.250.68:80"})
    opener = urllib2Local.build_opener(proxy_h)  
    urllib2Local.install_opener(opener)  
    req = urllib2Local.Request(url, Post, headers)
    response = urllib2Local.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()

def __post(self, post_args, tokenizer):
    Post = urllib.urlencode(post_args, doseq=True)
    headers = {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)", 
                #"Host": "servicios.mitele.es", 
                #"Accept-Encoding": "gzip", 
                "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", 
                "Referer": "http://static1.tele-cinco.net/comun/swf/playerMitele.swf",
                "Connection": "close", 
                "Accept-Language": "de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3", 
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                }
    #conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("213.4.97.107", 80)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("servicios.mitele.es", 80)
    conn.set_tunnel("80.58.250.68", 80, headers)
    conn.request("POST", tokenizer, Post, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()

    #print response.status, response.reason
    if response.status == 404: #NOT FOUND
        data = None
    elif response.status == 400: #BAD REQUEST
        data = None
    else:
        data = response.read()
    conn.close()
    return data
```

I need to do this because I have a website that finds the download links to the videos of the websites of the major Spanish televisions, and some are locked geographically and I need to make requests through a Spanish proxy. I can not use a web proxy because the request must be POST format.

Is there any way to do HTTP POST requests through a proxy in Google App Engine?

Any help much appreciated.. Sorry for my english.